# Can ANY compact set in $\mathbb R$ (which is not closed and bounded interval and $\varnothing$) be written as $[a,b] - \bigcup\limits_{n} I_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

> Let K be a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb R$  . Prove that $K$ is of the form $[a,b]$ or of the form $$[a,b] - \bigcup\limits_{n} I_n $$ where $I_n $ is a countable disjoint family of  open intervals with end points in $K$.

Will this statement be true?

**My Try** : I think this statement is true. As $K$  will be contained in any closed interval $[a,b]$ where $a , b \in K$. and $K$ will be a closed So $\mathbb R - K$  is the union of countable union of disjoint open intervals . $\mathbb R - K  = \bigcup\limits_{n} I_n$.$\;$ So $K = [a,b] - \bigcup\limits_{n} I_n $

Am I correct? Can anyone please mention where did I wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you did something wrong? Your proof is correct.

Comment: How about $\varnothing$?

Comment: Actually some problems have been posted earlier where the compact set $K$ had to have non empty interior . @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: edited....……. @Sobi

Comment: You still have to convince yourself that the intervals $I_n$ have endpoints in $K$.

Comment: @WilliamElliot It is assumed that the endpoints of the open intervals are in $K$.

Comment: @Sobi.  It is assumed K is not empty.

Comment: @WilliamElliot It was not assumed when I wrote my comment...

Comment: @cmi You should edit your question. "As $K$  will be contained in **any** closed interval $[a,b]$ where $a , b \in K$" is misleading. What you mean is "As $K$  will be contained in **some** closed interval $[a,b]$ where $a , b \in K$". In fact, $a = \min K, b = \max K$.